# How can I share the control of a Telegram bot between two or more users?

Tags: telegram-bot

Maybe it's not possible because I don't see any reference at http://botsfortelegram.com/project/the-bot-father/ but, how can I share control of a bot between users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by sharing control? Bots have tokens so everyone who has its token can control the bot. If you mean control by BotFather, no you can't. just owner of bots can control them.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about BotFather. 
Thanks!